# Align resized tikzpicture in subfigures

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, vertical-alignment, subcaption

I want to scale some of my tikzpicture in subfigures along the y axis to save some space. But when scaled the pictures don't align anymore.
I want to scale them to save vertical space.
I do not want to scale the height of the axis directly because then (auto) minor ticks disappear, (btw I would really like to have them in the right figure,too).
What I have is

[image: What I have]

What I want is (or similar)

[image: What I want]

My code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{filecontents}{tabelle1.tex}
4   36.56   26.68
128 24298.04 300000
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{tabelle2.tex}
4   24004.4 24004.4
64  240034.08   251182.32
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\hrule
\begin{figure}[tbph]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{% %I want to them to fit in their subfigure
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \footnotesize
                \begin{axis}[
                    yscale=0.7 % needed to reduce vertical space
                    ,height=\textwidth % fixed height and width for both, should lead to same scaling 
                    ,width=\textwidth % and therefore same size in the end, letting them sit together nicely
                    ,xtick=data
                    ,axis y line=left
                    ,ymin=10
                    ,ymode=log 
                    ,legend style={at={(1,0.1)},anchor=south east} % turn this off and its somewhere it should not be
                    ]                   
                    \addplot table [x index=0,y index=1] {tabelle1.tex};\addlegendentry{A}
                    \addplot table [x index=0,y index=2] {tabelle1.tex};\addlegendentry{B}
                \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \caption{a caption}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \footnotesize
                \begin{axis}[
                    yscale=0.7
                    ,height=\textwidth
                    ,width=\textwidth
                    ,xtick=data
                    ,axis y line=left
                    ,ymin=10000
                    ,ymode=log
                    ,legend style={at={(1,0.1)},anchor=south east}
                    ]
                    \addplot table [x index=0,y index=1] {tabelle2.tex};\addlegendentry{A}
                    \addplot table [x index=0,y index=2] {tabelle2.tex};\addlegendentry{B}
                \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \caption{b caption}     
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{main caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

So far I found out that there seems to be some connection between `yscale`, `ymode` and `legend style`.
Turning `yscale` or `ymode` off makes it work. `legend style` sometimes does, could not find a rule. The target was compiled without `yscale`.
I want all three of them. To be precise: something that delivers the same result.

How do I achieve this?

I have more similar figures so if I learn something from it, all the better. If necessary, rewriting everything is ok.

Comment: Don't use `yscale` on the `axis`. Rather, use something like `height=0.8\textwidth` (since you add this option anyways). You can then just add `legend pos=south east`.

Comment: The solutions of Zarko and Simon Dispa both worked to the extent I tested them. It comes down where to want to manually configure. Ultimately Zarkos solution was closer to mine, meaning less work to implement, thats why I used his.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
Added are y-axis labels and more correct adopt diagrams width to width of `\subfigure`s.

Rather than scaling picture is better to adapt their width to width of `subfigure`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
    \begin{filecontents}{tabelle1.tex}
    4   36.56   26.68
    128 24298.04 300000
    \end{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{tabelle2.tex}
    4   24004.4 24004.4
    64  240034.08   251182.32
    \end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[tbph]
\pgfplotsset{
    height=6cm, 
    width = \linewidth,     % <---
    xtick = data,
%    axis y line=left,      % <--- if you liked
    legend pos=south east,
            }
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}\raggedright
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
    ymin=10,
    ylabel = some text,
                    ]
\addplot table [x index=0,y index=1] {tabelle1.tex};
\addplot table [x index=0,y index=2] {tabelle1.tex};
    \legend{A, B}
\end{semilogyaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{subfigure A caption}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}\raggedleft
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
    ymin=10000,
    ylabel = some text,
                    ]
\addplot table [x index=0,y index=1] {tabelle2.tex};
\addplot table [x index=0,y index=2] {tabelle2.tex};
    \legend{A, B}
\end{semilogyaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{subfigure B caption}
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{Main caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text box borders)

Comment: that answered what I asked and I like it very much. Problem is, if I add ",ylabel={somelabel}" to both figures the right one gets again pushed out. Do you also know how to figure ylabels in? Or is that a new question?

Comment: @Sebastian, sorry, from your question is not clear, that you like to have any label at pictures, Of course adding it require that diagrams are narrowed. BTW, if you liked answer "very much", than you may consider to upvote it :-).

Comment: @Sebastian, see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using a 2 col x 1 row group to align the figures.

The subcaptions were inserted as nodes for easier configuration and positioning.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\usepackage{caption,subcaption}  

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{filecontents}{tabelle1.tex}
    4   36.56   26.68
    128 24298.04 300000
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{tabelle2.tex}
    4   24004.4 24004.4
    64  240034.08   251182.32
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[!htp]
        \centering\footnotesize
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{groupplot}[
                group style={
                    group name=my plots,
                    group size= 2 by 1,
                    horizontal sep =2.0cm,
                },
            legend style={at={(1.0,0.05)},anchor=south east},
            height=0.45\textwidth,
            width=0.45\textwidth,
            xtick=data,
            axis y line=left,
            ymode=log
                ]
                \nextgroupplot[ymin=10]                   
                    \addplot table [x index=0,y index=1] {tabelle1.tex};\addlegendentry{A}
                    \addplot table [x index=0,y index=2] {tabelle1.tex};\addlegendentry{B}
                
                \nextgroupplot[ymin=10000]
                \addplot table [x index=0,y index=1] {tabelle2.tex};\addlegendentry{A}
                \addplot table [x index=0,y index=2] {tabelle2.tex};\addlegendentry{B}
            \end{groupplot}
    
            \tikzset{SubCaption/.style={
                    text width=0.4\textwidth,
                    yshift=-3mm, 
                    align=center,anchor=north
            }}
            
            \node[SubCaption] at (my plots c1r1.south) {\subcaption{First graph a}\label{subplot:one}};         
            \node[SubCaption] at (my plots c2r1.south) {\subcaption{Second graph b}\label{subplot:two}};

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Main caption}\label{fig:plots}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

I don't think you need the arrow for the y-axis. Using `axis y line*=left,` you will get

[image: c]